# jQuery: Add a String to URL

Tags: jquery, string, url, href

I'm using this snippet of code to grab a url from a clicked link:

```
var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

I want to add a string to that url.

For example, my current url is:

http://mydomain.com/myarticle

I want to make it:

http://mydomain.com/myarticle-chinese

What should I add to my initial line of code to make that happen?

I'd be grateful for your advice!

**ADDENDUM: THANK YOU VERY MUCH! FOUR PEOPLE ANSWERED ALMOST SIMULTANEOUSLY AND ALL FOUR GAVE ME A HELPFUL ANSWER. I WISH I COULD ACCEPT ALL FOUR!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href') + "-chinese";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var $a = $(this).find('a');
var url = $a.attr('href');
$a.attr('href', url + '-chinese');
```

Answer (score 2):

This will store the new value in `url`:

```
var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href') + '-chinese';
```

and this will redirect the user's browser:

```
window.location.href = $(this).find('a').attr('href') + '-chinese'
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to append the string "-chinese" to the retrieved URL? Try this:

```
var url = $(this).find('a').attr('href') + '-chinese';
```