# Append "&html5=1" to video URL's on YouTube? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, url, youtube, append

I couldn't manage to find anything on how to use Jquery to append **&html5=1** to the video results on search/feed/subscriptions and such to all video URL's.

The following are links that **MAY** contribute to a solution:

Example 1:
http://jsfiddle.net/WFd79/

Example 2:
[YouTube video in HTML not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17795691)

Example 3:

```
function main(){    
    //Standard Logo
    document.getElementById('.yt-lockup.yt-lockup-tile a.ux-thumb-wrap').setAttribute('href', 'http://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions');
}
main();
```

Note: If commas can be used to append to multiple ID's or classes such as titles plus thumbnails, would be more user friendly. This is also not needing a solution for **embeds** or **iframes**.

Note 2: I use tampermonkey extension to inject jquery.

***P.S. I thank anyone who attemps to find a solution or has one so others may benefit from this as well.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the most elegant way, but it seems to be working:

```
$(".yt-lockup A.yt-uix-sessionlink").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return href + '&html5=1';
});
```

From:

1. #### https://stackoverflow.com/a/2805905/2038928
2. http://community.sitepoint.com/t/jquery-append-query-string-to-href/6003
3. [Append Query String to URL with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16408692/)
4. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6934732/2038928